# javascript sort some elements of an array into other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop

for a project i have to sort this array containing strings and numbers. the string serves as indicator for which array the number should be stored into.

```
let myArray = [22, 'talk', 31, 'perfo', 35, 'init', 42, 'talk']
let talk = []
let perfo = []
let init = []

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i + 2) {
    if (myArray[i + 1] == 'talk') {
        talk.push(myArray[i])
    } else if (myArray[i + 1] == 'perfo') {
        perfo.push(myArray[i])
    } else if (myArray[i + 1] == 'init') {
        init.push(myArray[i])
    } else {}
}
```

expected result :

```
talk [22, 42], perfo [35], init [42]
```

but somehow it doesn't seem like it's even getting trough the for loop.

Comment: Is there some reason why you're incrementing `i` by 2 on each iteration?

Comment: Your code works, except for a small error - Increment `i` by using `i += 2`.

Comment: This is not called "sorting", but rather "grouping" or "splitting".

Comment: In addition remove the redundant `else {}`.

Comment: (…or better "partitioning" than "splitting")

Comment: Thank @OriDrori that was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object is the same as an array, but instead of having a number as an index, it has a string, thus we can use an object to reconstruct the initial array.

```js
let myArray = [22, 'talk', 31, 'perfo', 35, 'init', 42, 'talk']

let arrays = {}
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i+=2) {
  const arrayName = myArray[i+1];
  
  if (arrays[arrayName]) {
    arrays[arrayName].push(myArray[i])
  } else {
    arrays[arrayName] = [myArray[i]]
  }
}

console.log(arrays);
// [object Object] {
//  init: [35],
//  perfo: [31],
//  talk: [22, 42]
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with the wanted arrays and push the values to it.

```js
let data = [22, 'talk', 31, 'perfo', 35, 'init', 42, 'talk'],
    talk = [],
    perfo = [],
    init = [],
    temp = { talk, perfo, init },
    i = 0;

while (i < data.length) {
    let [value, key] = data.slice(i, i += 2);
    temp[key].push(value);
}

console.log(talk);
console.log(perfo);
console.log(init);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```